# Non-independence of data in regression model

Tags: regression, mixed-model

I have a problem concerning non-independence of data in an experimental economic game. Participants are in groups of three and interact with each of the other two. Each interaction between persons A and B is characterised by two variables, how generous A is to B and how much A reports liking B (and the same for B to A). Firstly I want to look at reciprocity of generosity: I model generosity_A_to_B = generosity_B_to_A, including identity of A as a random factor because A has interactions with two people. But I have a nagging feeling that maybe B's identity should also be included as a random factor? Because if I don't, won't the model be different depending on who in a pair is A and who is B? In any case I can't include both identities as random factors, I get a "rank deficiency" error.

The real fun starts when I want to know how A's generosity to B depends on how much A likes B, controlling for reciprocation. The model is generosity_A_to_B = A_likes_B + generosity_B_to_A. Running this model including all the data, so that for each pair person 1 is A and person 2 is B, and then also person 1 is B and person 2 is A, seems to me intuitively not OK. It seems like pseudoreplication because each pair is first included with person 1 modeled by person 2's values, then vice versa. But if I don't do this, then half my data is thrown away, because A_likes_B has a different value depending on whether A is person 1 or person 2. And again, how to try and include identity as a random factor? My mind boggles.

Comment: Do you have multiple measures of each variable over time? Eg, each iteration / interaction between people yielding a new measure of liking & generosity.

Comment: Have you ever looked into social network analysis? Seems like that might be more fitting.

Comment: @gung: I do have multiple measures but I'm trying to keep it simple to start off by using the mean values.